back button with useNavigate() replace: true is not triggering beforeunload for safari only
I'm using react-router-dom and useNavigate() function. When the user goes from "/home/" to "/home/room", I'm doing navigate("/home/room", { replace: true }) so that when the user clicks back in browser, they can't go back to home, and instead the browser unloads.
I also have a beforeunload listener to have user confirm they want to leave.
useEffect(() => {
  const unloadCallback = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = "";
    return "";
  };
  
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", unloadCallback);
  return () => window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", unloadCallback);
});

Everything is working fine in Chrome and Firefox, however it's not working in Safari. I navigate from "/home" to "/home/room" and click back, and the confirmation of unload is not happening, and I can just go back to "/home/" and then click forward back into "/home/room". What I really want to avoid because clicking back SHOULD remove the room.

I've rolled back your tags change again, the React-Router library hasn't anything at all to do with what the Safari browser does outside your React app and running Javascript is doing. If for some reason you think RRD is relevant, then [edit] to include a complete [mcve] that includes RRD code.

If you can, try to create a running codesandbox demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live.

I made a new post and will close this one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78286616/socket-reconnects-after-disconnecting-in-safari-only-in-react-node-socket-io
I think the react-router's redirect isn't completely working though in this case so I think it's still relevant

It's hard to create a demo that shows ONLY safari actions so not sure how to do that but included a lot of code in the new post
